# reformatting report file using linux shell commands combining multiple lines output into one

Tags: linux, sed, awk, format

I have a file that contains the following input:

```
name: ted 
position:11.11.11.11"
applicationKey:88
channel:45
protocol:4
total:350

name:janet
position:170.198.80.209
applicationKey:256
channel:44
protocol:4
total:1
```

I like the out put to look like this

```
tedd  11.11.11.11 88 45 4 350
janet 170.198.80.209 256 44 4 1
```

Can someone help with this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk -F':' '{printf "%s %s",$2,ORS=NF?"":"\n"}END{print "\n"}' file
```

```
$ cat file
name:ted
position:11.11.11.11
applicationKey:88
channel:45
protocol:4
total:350

name:janet
position:170.198.80.209
applicationKey:256
channel:44
protocol:4
total:1
```

```
$ awk -F':' '{printf "%s %s",$2,ORS=NF?"":"\n"}END{print "\n"}' file
ted 11.11.11.11 88 45 4 350 
janet 170.198.80.209 256 44 4 1
```